# how to save nc command output while checking SMTP port

Tags: linux, console, smtp

I am using following linux command to check SMTP port 25

```
timeout 5 nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 25
```

which returns this

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:25.
```

I would save the output in a file but I can not find a way to do that,
I tried this

```
timeout 5 nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 25 > output.txt
```

and

```
timeout 5 nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 25  2>&1 > output.txt
```

but the output.txt file is always empty. How can I save the nc output in a file
in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```
timeout 5 nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 25 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```